# Define a norm using a pseudo norm

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space with a pseudo norm $\rho$ defined on it.

1. Find a subspace $W$ of $V$ such that $X=V/W$ is a normed space with a norm $\|\cdot \|$
2. Find a linear map $T:V\to X$ such that $\rho(x)=\|T(x)\|$ for each $x\in V$.

How does one start off with this problem? I haven't found any way to start thinking about it. How do I get a norm, from a pseudo norm? Can someone help me out? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Look at the set where $\rho$ is zero. Sending too many vectors to zero is what makes a semi-norm not be a norm. And after you get (1) look at the quotient map $V\to V/W$.